# Semantic UI Sidebar pushes elements outside of screen width

Tags: html, css, sidebar, semantic-ui

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if this is the intended result but the I'm using semantic ui's sidebar and it pushes everything past the max screen width. Am I missing something here?

```
<div class="ui bottom attached segment pushable">
  <div class="ui left vertical menu visible thin attached inverted sidebar">
    <a class="item">
          Item 1
        </a>
    <a class="item">
          Item 2
        </a>
    <a class="item">
          Item 3
        </a>
  </div>
  <div class="pusher">
    <div id="search-bar">
      <div class="ui fluid action input">
        <input placeholder="Search..">
        <div class="ui green button"> Search </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="ui block header">
      Item
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kour6d1x/

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am too looking for the same.

Comment: Same question did you figure this out ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the content "pushed" for the [Semantic UI sidebars](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html) you should use the `.overlay` class on it - [relevant demos](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html#/examples)

Like the class name suggests, it will overlay the sidebar rather than pushing the content along with it.

Add `overlay` class to the `<div class="ui left vertical menu visible thin attached inverted sidebar">` element.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gj46Loos/)

Comment: Any idea on how I can have it pushed but still have the max-width set appropriately for the screen size?

Comment: @RoshephJackson I am not sure I follow - if the content is being pushed, it shouldn't overflow and allow the user to scroll, if this is happening, then something is wrong with the markup

Comment: To get a nice "appearing menu" effect, you'd want the content to be pushed, but also to reduce its width, not to overflow. E.g if you want the menu to usually stay on the left but also to be hideable. Overlay is not adapted are the menu is not meant to stay.

Answer (score 1):

I have used below css to reduce thr width of pusher when sidebar is open. In below code `58px` is the width of sidebar

```
.sidebar.visible + .pusher{
    margin-right: 58px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom CSS subtracting the width of the sidebar would do the trick:

```
.sidebar.visible + .pusher {
  width: calc(100% - 260px);
}
```